# Can な Adjectives be also used for combination with verbs

Tags: verbs, て-form, adjectives, na-adjectives

I am new to Japanese and found out that Adjectives can also be used along with verbs in て forms. I came to know that there are two adjectives い-adj and な-adj. い is an adjectival verb. Whereas, な is an adjectival noun.

So, my question is whether な-adjectives also in there て form merged/mix with verbs. Can you give examples please, if possible

Answer (score 2):

Both i-adjectives and na-adjectives **conjugate** in Japanese.  The conjugation form that allows adjectives to modify verbs (and other adjectives) is called 「連用形{れんようけい}」 ("continuative form").

With na-adjectives, the 連用形 comes in the form 「〇〇**に**」, which means that you only need to change the final 「な」 to a 「に」.

しずか**な**人{ひと} = "a quiet person"

しずか**に**食{た}べる = "to eat quietly"

Fairly simple, isn't it?  You can expect to use this rule all your life, too.

元気{げんき}**な**こども = "a vigorous child"

元気**に**生{い}きる = "to live vigorously"

**Please remember that there is no such thing as the te-form for na-adjectives.  Moreover, even with i-adjectives, it is misleading to say that the te-form modifies verbs**.  It is again the 連用形 that modifies verbs for i-adjectives as well.

For the 連用形 of an i-adjective, simply change the final 「い」 to a 「く」.

うま**い**歌手{かしゅ} = "a good singer"

うま**く**歌{うた}う = "to sing well"

It is utterly incorrect to say 「うまく**て**歌う」 and I certainly hope you did not learn that it is correct.

高{たか}**い**空{そら} = "high skies"

高**く**飛{と}ぶ = "to fly high"

We never say 「高く**て**飛ぶ」.

Comment: ありがと。I have a grammar book, Complete Grammar by Eriko Sako there it is written that there is a て form. He has given examples as well I'll give a photo  by editing the question. It didn't give the example of na adj used as mix of verb. However in that it is stated that we add て in the end. And one more.question, can we use は particle after adjective. I can't think of any situations but if we can, could you please give me examples? Please.

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1uvFd9NyM42J7Ta3AFbm0bVcOTExW6vap?usp=sharing) here is the Google Drive link. Sorry, the photo wasn't getting below 2 MB. I tried it on 10 different websites